# How do I find all questions answers and comments that link to my site?

Tags: feature-request

Let's say I'm a large organization with online documentation for an extensive API.

At the bottom of each page in my API reference doc I'd like to have a button that says "show incoming links from stackexchange (n)" where n is the number of links.  When the user clicks on this button I would like to present a list of stackexchange posts sorted by score.

I don't see anything in the [Stackexhange api](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage) that I could use to accomplish this.

[Dogfood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) for dinner anyone?

This would allow people to quickly locate discussions about a particular part of my API in a stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is not time-critical (you don't need to index posts the second they're created), it would be easier to use [data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/). Just go through the list of posts using your favourite language, no http requests involved.

You can also monitor latest questions periodically with simple [/questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=questions) request and add *new* incoming links to your database.